# Checkbox mat-table issue - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I'm adding a checkbox to a mat-table, but I found a possible bug. To reproduce it, you have to do the following:

1. Click on the global checkbox to select all rows
2. Decheck some checkboxes from the rows
3. Re-select the unchecked checkboxes
4. Click repeatedly on the head of the table to order the rows
5. See how the selected checkboxes flash when ordering the rows

The following gif shows how to reproduce it with the example below.

[image: gif highlighting how to reproduce the issue]

1. In [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9p1ppm) you can reproduce the error
2. [This example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-table-wjmlw9) does not have that error but it is an old version of mat-table

Comment: I reported about this error in the git of angular material and have already solved it, it will be ready for the next version